# Trying to find a unix account in my Windows domain that is not in AD

Tags: unix, active-directory, ldap

I'm been tasked with managing an AD domain in a primarily unix oriented server environment. One of my colleagues tells me there is a unix account that appears to exist in Active Directory. In his search he find an account named for instance `unixaccount@ad.domain.local` - ad.domain.local being the AD domain.

In `Active Directory Users and Computers` I do a search for `unixaccount*` in the entire directory, but nothing comes up.
One theory of my colleague is that when they initially set up their Windows environment they may not have know how to do it correctly and that there may be old LDAP accounts laying around that is not in AD. So my question is, how can I find such old LDAP accounts that is not in AD, but appears as they are an AD account when searching for it in a unix system?

Comment: *"One of my colleagues tells me there is a unix account that appears to exist in Active Directory."* - This simply isn't possible. If it shows up in an AD search, then it's an AD account. There could be an AD account with the same username as a Unix account, but that doesn't mean they're related in any way - they just have the same name.